# Push Notification to particular device in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating an Android app where in I will require the push notifications.

I can send notifications to multiple Devices very perfectly..There is no issue at all..

Here the query is How can I  send Notification to particular device (or user).

Like for example, If any 1 user's balance is low, then I want to generate Notification to particular that user.

What should be done to send the push notification to the particular individual user in Android?

Please Help and Suggest.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think that sending to one device is any different than sending to multiple devices?

Comment: @CommonsWare..In my App, There is tree kind of clients so i want to send a push Notification to particular clients only..not to all the clients..so This requirement makes me think like this..As I mentioned in my question..low balance notification to particular clients only..

Comment: My point is that you already know how to do this. Instead of using GCM to send to 2, 3, 4, or 5 devices, you use GCM to send to 1 user. There is no change to the way you use GCM to send to 1 device compared to sending to more than 1 device.

Comment: @CommonsWare.. I am using GCM for sending notification. I can send notification to 2,3,4,5 as well as only 1 device. but How can I recognize Particular device to which I want to give Notification??

Answer (score 3):

This [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html) suggests that when your app registers for cloud-to-device messages, it will receive a registration ID. You should have the app report this registration ID to your servers, where you can then supply it to the C2DM servers as required.

Comment: C2DM was a perfect solution. But now it is getting deprecated. So it is better to have a solution with GCM just like @CommonsWare mentioning in his comment.

Comment: You are Perfectly right but How can I recognize particular Registration ID of Particular Client?

Comment: @RiddhiBarbhaya: By looking up the registration ID in the database that you are maintaining on your server, matching registration IDs with users. **You already have this database**, otherwise you have no means of sending *any* GCM messages, because you would not have the registration IDs to use for sending.

Comment: C2DM was officially deprecated on June 26, 2012, and has been shut down completely as of October 20, 2015. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?csw=1